# Is Groovy .collect() an equivalent of JS .map()?

Tags: javascript, groovy

Is Groovy .collect() an equivalent of JS .map()? Or is there another purpose?

Comment: I've written a dozen lines of Groovy in total and I've never even seen `.collect` but it seems that it's equivalent. Took me brief googling to find that. Do you have a reason to believe the two aren't equivalent? Because otherwise it doesn't seem like a very good question.

Comment: the name was confusing. First thought of mine was "maybe it's not completelly equivalent"... Thx for clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can do a few other things too (like initial collection), but otherwise it's pretty much the same:

```
// Collect without
// initial collection.
assert [1,2,8] == [1,4,64].collect(Math.&sqrt)
assert [0,2,4,6] == (0..3).collect { it * 2 }
assert ['Groovy', 'Grails'] == [lang: 'Groovy', framework: 'Grails'].collect { it.value }
 
// Collect with initial collection argument.
assert [0, 1, 2, 3] == [2, 3].collect([0, 1]) { it }
assert [0, 3, 6, 9] == [2, 3].collect([0, 3], { it * 3})
assert ['Gradle', 'groovy', 'grails'] == ['Groovy', 'Grails'].collect(['Gradle']) { it.toLowerCase() }
assert ['m','r','h','a','k','i'] == [4, -3, 7, 5].collect(['m', 'r']) { (it + 100) as char }
```

PS. credit for examples to [mrhaki](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.au/2010/05/groovy-goodness-use-collect-with.html)'s excellent Groovy Goodness blog

Comment: Thanks for explanation! So they're different.

Comment: It's just `collect` can iterate over a lot more things (maps, strings, other objects, collections), while `map` in JavaScript is operating on arrays only. When opearting on arrays or lists or other "collections" in groovy its functionality is similar otherwise.

Comment: Also: `[a:'1', b:'2'].collect { k, v -> "$k$v" }`

Answer (score 1):

yes, `collect()` allows you to transform collection element's type or structure:

```
def strings = [ '1', '2', '3' ]
assert String == strings.first().getClass()
def nums = strings.collect{ it as Integer }
assert Integer == nums.first().getClass()
```